# Rails - Twitter::Error::BadRequest (Bad Authentication data) - After Deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, heroku, twitter-oauth

In my app, I'm providing users to tweet with the following code:

```
       if twitter = current_user.authentications.find_by_provider("twitter")
        Twitter.configure do |tw|
          tw.consumer_key = "6jaqMt7kE9iVxh8hX0mmtQ"
          tw.consumer_secret = "5ZIydxRBFfEJxc2EzedahIxoeO8g1hZCQVqZFtWWNM"
          tw.oauth_token = twitter.token
          tw.oauth_token_secret = twitter.token_secret
        end
        Twitter.update(params[:tweet])
```

It works well in my localhost. However now I've deployed my app to heroku, and I'm trying to send tweets, but in heroku logs it says:

```
2012-11-15T01:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 494ms
2012-11-15T01:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-15T01:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Twitter::Error::BadRequest (Bad Authentication data):
2012-11-15T01:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-15T01:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-15T01:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

What should I do to solve this problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've figured out the Twitter Authentication and wrote a tutorial with my experiences: http://www.orhancanceylan.com/rails-twitter-and-facebook-authentications-with-omniauth-and-devise/

Comment: Please repost/edit your answer so the important points of the answer are posted here, on *this* site.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Update your callback URL to your production server location, in your registered Twitter application's settings.
2. If you're using a subdomain of herokuapp.com, guess what, you're in a pool of a bazillion other API requests to Twitter. [Proxy your API requests through Apigee](http://apigee.com/docs/enterprise/content/get_started_api).
3. Initialize then migrate your database on Heroku through your console:

   `heroku run rake db:setup`

   `heroku run rake db:migrate`

(normally just rake db:migrate works, but I had to do both in this case)

Sourced from the [Twitter dev discussions](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3955)